# R - convert a 2-d vector into a 1-d named vector

Tags: r, purrr

How can this be done more elegantly?  I'm looking to convert a vector of key value pairs as concatenated strings, into a vector of values with the keys as names.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

x <- c("key1|value1", "key2|value2")

# Current way
x_split <- x %>% str_split("\\|")
keys <- x_split %>% map(pluck(1)) %>% unlist()
values <- x_split %>% map(pluck(2)) %>% unlist()

y <- values %>% set_names(keys)

# More elegant way
y <- x %>% some_functions()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `simplify = TRUE` in `str_split` and use `set_names`.

```
stringr::str_split(x, "\\|", simplify = TRUE) %>% {purrr::set_names(.[, 2], .[, 1])}

#    key1     key2 
#"value1" "value2"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked `data.table::tstrsplit`.

```
library(data.table)
tstrsplit(x,"\\|") %>% {setNames(.[[2]],.[[1]])}
#    key1     key2 
#"value1" "value2"
```